# Java: How do I set two variables to the same value, then change one without changing the other?

Tags: java

I'm attempting to create a recursive method to calculate exponents.  I set `product` equal to `base` using a constructor.  The problem is when I execute my `power` method, each time `product` is manipulated by the method `base`changes to the same value.

```
   public Power (double base, double exponent) {  //constructor
          this.base = base;
          this.exponent = exponent;
          product = base;
   }

   public void setBase(double base) {  //set base variable, set product equal to base
       this.base = base;
       product = base;
   }

   public double power(double base, double exponent) {  //calculates base^exponent = product
       if(exponent == 1) {
           return product;
       }
       product = product * base;
       return power( product,  (exponent - 1 ) );
   }
```

}

As a result 2^3 = 16.  This is incorrect.  The expected outcome should be 2^3  = 8.  Is there a way to set the value of `product` equal to `base` prior to the `power` method and prevent them from changing value together during the recursive method?

Comment: You need to make exponent an integer. Now you can set it to 1.1 and it will never finish

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation mixes fields and method parameters, shadowing `exponent` variable which makes the code hard to read. Recursive method doesn't require fields as it uses stack to pass values from a nested function call.

The problem is in `power(base * base, exp - 1)` logic as you are squaring. The first call recursive call for 2^3 will do `power(2 * 2, 3 - 1)`, then `power(4 * 4, 2 - 1)`, then return `16`.

It should be:

```
public int power(int base, int exponent) {
    if (exponent == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (exponent == 1) {
        return base;
    }
    return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current design can lead to a class state that is inconsistent.  You could call `setBase()` or `power()` multiple times, and then have `base`, `exponent` and `product` make no sense when taken together as a whole.

I would make it so that you only pass in `base` and `exponent` to the constructor, then after that they are read-only.  The recursive method would only get called once from the constructor.  The three values would then be retrieved with getter methods so they can't be changed after the fact.

Something like:

```
public class Power
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Power p1 = new Power(2, 3);
        Power p2 = new Power(3, 4);
        Power p3 = new Power(5, 2);
        System.out.println(p1);
        System.out.println(p2);
        System.out.println(p3);
    }

    private int base;
    private int exponent;
    private int product;

    private Power() {}

    public Power (int base, int exponent) {  
        this.base = base;
        this.exponent = exponent;
        this.product = power(base, exponent);
    }

    private int power(int base, int exponent) { 
        return (exponent == 0) ? 1 : base * power(base, --exponent);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return base + "^" + exponent + " = " + product;
    }

    private double getBase()
    {
       return base;
    }

    private double getExponent()
    {
       return exponent;
    }

    private double getProduct()
    {
       return product;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
2^3 = 8
3^4 = 81
5^2 = 25
```